# Grammars in compiler design

Tags: compiler-construction

I am looking for answers for the below question, this is regarding to grammars concept in compiler design.

Show that the following grammar is LL(1) but SLR(1)

```
S.L     S -> SA|A
        A -> a
```

Comment: homework problem? Have you attempted something yourself already?

Comment: not yet... i have no idea

Comment: Am I reading something wrong? Isn't this language {a^n|n>=1}, if so, it is regular. That makes it trivially in both classes if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at videos in section 7 - 9

[Compilers with Alex Aiken](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sm0QQO-WZlM&list=PLFB9EC7B8FE963EB8)

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Create a LL(1) parsing table
   If there are no conflicts then the grammar is LL(1)
2. Create a SLR(1) parsing table
   If there are no conflicts then the grammar is SLR(1)